# Print a result into a data frame with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a `dataframe` such as:

```
col1  col2  col3  ID 
A  23  AZ  ER1  ID1
B  12  ZE  EZ1  ID2
C  13  RE  RE1  ID3
```

I parsed the ID col in order to get some informations, to be quick, for each ID I get some informations, here is a result of the code:

```
for i in dataframe['ID']:
    name = function(i,ranks=True)
    print(name)

{'species': 'rabbit', 'genus': 'unis', 'subfamily': 'logomorphidae', 'family': 'lego', 'no rank': 'info, nothing', 'superkingdom': 'eucoryote'}
{'species': 'dog', 'genus': 'Rana', 'subfamily': 'Alphair', 'family': 'doggidae', 'no rank': 'dsDNA , no  stage', 'superkingdom': 'eucaryote'}
{'species': 'duck', 'subfamily': 'duckinae', 'family': 'duckidae'}
...
```

as you can se it is a dictionary return. As you can also see for the ID 1 and 2 I get 6 informations `(species, genus, subfamily, family,no rank,superkingdom)`
for the ID 3 I only get 3 informations
And the idea is instead of just print the dic contents to add it directly in the `dataframe` and get :

```
col1  col2  col3 ID  species   genus    subfamily      family     no rank           superkingdom
A  23  AZ  ER1  ID1  rabbit    unis     logomorphidae  lego       info, nothing,    eucaryote
B  12  ZE  EZ1  ID2  dog       Rana     Alphair        doggidae   dsDNA , no stage  eucaryote 
C  13  RE  RE1  ID3  duck      None     duckinae       duckidae   None              None
```

Have you an idea to do it with pandas? 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your output in a `dict` of `dicts`, making it easy to create a `DataFrame` and join it back.

```
d = {}
for i in dataframe['ID']:
    d[i] = taxid.lineage_name(i, ranks=True)

df.merge(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index'), left_on='ID', right_index=True)
```

#### Output:

```
   col1 col2 col3   ID species genus      subfamily    family            no rank superkingdom
A    23   AZ  ER1  ID1  rabbit  unis  logomorphidae      lego      info, nothing    eucoryote
B    12   ZE  EZ1  ID2     dog  Rana        Alphair  doggidae  dsDNA , no  stage    eucaryote
C    13   RE  RE1  ID3    duck   NaN       duckinae  duckidae                NaN          NaN
```